# Android : authentication to php server application

Tags: android, authentication, symfony, web, oauth-2.0

Am triying to build a mobile(android) version of my PHP/Symfony application. I need to build an authentication system on the mobile device.
There is an intuitive method, that lies on sending a post http request with the data entered by the user and then use shared preferences.
Till now, everything may be good, but I was wondering about all the user profile/permissions stuff.

Is there any one that could help me with some ideas or hints ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle) let you implement very easy OAuth authentication for mobile apps.

Comment: Am wondering how the logic works, I mean is the server going to send a user object back to the mobile application including the relations... ? and if so, how is the data retreived bach in the mobile side?  Thanks Bro !

Comment: I think this is the point- when you do auth with the server you do auth WITH the server. It shouldn't help you with the phone (other than, say perhaps cosmetic tweaks to UI). Http auth should solely have the role of supplying access tokens for your http calls. You seem to be desiring to to have your application profile API to be on the phone, which is odd. Usually, you keep that server side and use authorization headers to make API calls that keep your app UI up to date.

Comment: Thanks Tom, But don't you think this is only possible when using the system browser. Am willing to avoid the browser, since the application is supposed to do all these web operations in background

Comment: I mean, is it possible to have back all the user's information?

Comment: the FOSOAuthServerBundle part is not realy clear to mee, cause i don't see how the data or even the generated key is obtained and sent back !

Comment: Your mobile application obtains an authentication key via OAuth (search for it, it's a standard). This authentication key is sended with every request to your REST API to obtain the data. You should inform you more about webservices in general.